# OnePlus 7t - Device unauthorized in recovery mode (but authorized when turned on)

Tags: adb, side-loading, authorization

I would like to install a clean Android 11 with `adb sideload`, but I've encountered a problem. When I rebooted to recovery and tried `adb sideload rom.zip` it gives me this error:

```
adb: sideload connection failed: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
```

Same output goes for `adb shell`

I have also tried to see what `adb devices` returns when in recovery and it shows my devices as unauthorized, although when my phone is normally turned on "adb devices" shows my device as authorized. I have tried some solutions found online, but any didn't work (for e.g.: revoking usb debbuging keys).
I don't know if that matters, but my phone is/have:

- rooted (but right now I don't have Magisk installed)
- unlocked bootloader,
- stock recovery.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try adb kill-server? Are you using stock recovery or something else?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm on stock recovery

Comment: Flash or boot into TWRP. TWRP would not give you device unauthorized problem when being accessed using adb. Also, I think the easiest way on a OnePlus device to flash stock ROM is to let the Settings app download the update and apply it. It works on a rooted device too.

Comment: I did as you said and when I've booted with TWRP and I've tried some commands there and ADB showed device as in recovery, but still side load didn't work. I know that the easiest way is to update form settings, but I just wanted to do a clean installation.

Comment: When you tried to sideload in TWRP, did you get the same error or was the error different?

Comment: I've tried it two times since after first try I've got a message in TWRP that it failed:
C:\~>adb sideload OnePlus7TOxygen_14.E.35_OTA_0350_all_2206171459_2d24e8424d684e1f.zip
Total xfer: 0.00x

And the second one:
C:\~>adb sideload OnePlus7TOxygen_14.E.35_OTA_0350_all_2206171459_2d24e8424d684e1f.zip
adb: sideload connection failed: closed

Anyway I think I will just flash it with fastboot since it's seems working. I've got another noob quesiton. Which partition should I choose (A or B), because I've tried switching them in TWRP and now I don't know which one was set at the start.

Comment: Did you follow the sideload instructions for TWRP? See https://forum.fairphone.com/t/update-to-lineage-17-1-not-possible-adb-sideload-connection-failed/65175/2 // You have to first enable Sideloading from TWRP Advanced settings and than issue adb sideload command.

Comment: I've tried that and after swiping to begin the process console brings up and shows starting ADB sideload feauture... and there is bar below with blue light running on it and that process seems not ending and I have only cancel button avaiable.

Comment: I've treid to flash on that screen with console in TWRP and that's what I've got:

`C:\Users\rzadd\Desktop\platform-tools>adb sideload OnePlus7TOxygen_14.E.35_OTA_0350_all_2206171459_2d24e8424d684e1f.zip
serving: 'OnePlus7TOxygen_14.E.35_OTA_0350_all_2206171459_2d24e8424d684e1f.zip'  (~0%)    adb: failed to read command: No error`

And in TWRP is says:
`Installing zip file /sideload/package.zip
Flashing A/B zip to inactive slot: A
To flash additional zips, plese reboot recovery to switch to updated slot.`